# Select unique value from multiple rows and columns in for single list value

Tags: mysql

I have table containing value like below:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
=====================================
1       | 3       | 5       | NULL
1       | 3       | NULL    | NULL
1       | 4       | NULL    | NULL
2       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
```

How is the query if i want the result only unique value and not null like below:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have 4 queries, one to select against each column and UNION the results together:-

```
SELECT Column1 AS aCol FROM SomeTable WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Column2 AS aCol FROM SomeTable WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Column3 AS aCol FROM SomeTable WHERE Column3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Column4 AS aCol FROM SomeTable WHERE Column4 IS NOT NULL
```

Or if you just want a single field returned with them all concantentated:-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(aCol)
FROM
(
    SELECT Column1 AS aCol FROM SomeTable 
    UNION
    SELECT Column2 AS aCol FROM SomeTable 
    UNION
    SELECT Column3 AS aCol FROM SomeTable 
    UNION
    SELECT Column4 AS aCol FROM SomeTable 
) Sub0
```